# IIS 7 Windows Authentication keeps showing login popup

Tags: iis-7

I'm trying to be able to login to a simple IIS7 website using windows authentication. I turned on Windows Authentication for the website and put NTLM at the top of the providers list.

When I access the page in web browser, I get the windows security login popup. I enter in my user name and password and click OK, but the windows login popup keeps popping up.  I am using a administrator username so it should not be a folder security issue.

Thanks!